# How to reformat/Erase my MAC Internal Hard disk using Terminal

Tags: macos, volume, erase, reformat

I am trying to reformat my MAC using Disk Utility but the buttons are grayed out (see image below)

[image: Via Disk Utility]

SO I tried to use the terminal but not sure on the steps. Please help on the next step on how to reformat my internal hard disk and reinstall the OS (MAC OS X Snow Leopard) Thanks.

[image: Via Terminal]

When I tried to create a partition it says " The disk is too small to contain partition" and the buttons are grayed out.

[image: When creating partition]

Comment: If you are really, absolutely sure you want to wipe out your main disk, detach all external drives first and then you can use `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0 bs=65536` and leave it to run a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes I am sure as I do not have any important files on my hard disk. running this code will reformat my main disk and I then I can reinstall the MAC OS?

Comment: It will certainly obliterate all partitions and data on your hard disk. I don't know what your Mac will do when it finds the empty disk after you reboot but I presume it has the smarts to download a new copy of macOS from the 'net but I don't fancy testing on my machine.

Comment: I tried the command code but it says sudo: command not found

Comment: Ok, try `/usr/bin/sudo dd if=/dev/zero if=/dev/disk0 bs=65536`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have your HDD unpartitioned. Try to first create a partition on that drive and then you should be able to install OS X on that volume.

Comment: Thanks. I tried creating a partition but I got an error saying the disk is too small to contain partition